# A characterization for semilocal rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, local-rings

A commutative ring with 1 is called semi-local if it has finitely many maximal ideals and is called local if it has only one maximal ideal. There are some algebraic charactrizations for local rings. For example a ring $R$ is local ring if and only if  all elements of $R$ that are not units form an ideal if and only if either $r$ or $1-r$ is unit for all $r\in R$. Is there **any** such  caracterizations for semi-local rings with more than one maximal ideals?

Comment: I’ve never seen anything I would call analogous for semilocal rings.

Answer (score 0):

I did some thinking and came to the conclusion that an analogous statement seems most likely for the slightly better class of semiperfect rings.

Recall that a ring is a *clean ring* if every element is the sum of an idempotent and a unit.

Proposition: a ring is local iff it is clean and has trivial idempotents.

You see, if $x$ is not already a unit, so that $x+0$ is such a decomposition, then $(x-1)+1$ works.

I think the analogous statement would be

Proposition: a ring is semiperfect iff it is clean and has a complete orthogonal set of primitive idempotents.

If the ring is commutative, then such a ring is a finite product of local rings, and every element can be expressed as $u+e$ where $e$ is the sum of finitely many elements of the complete orthogonal set.

I could not see a version specifically for semilocal rings. They can be a bit less nice.

Answer (score 0):

For proving things about a semi-local ring $R$, the following local-global property can be useful:

> If a polynomial $f \in R[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ represents a unit over
> $R_P$ for every maximal ideal $P$ of $R$, then $f$ represents a unit
> over $R$.

This property holds for semi-local rings and a few others, such as the ring of all algebraic integers.   A good reference for consequences of this property as well as some similar properties is the paper

- Estes, Dennis R., and Robert M. Guralnick. "Module equivalences: local to global when primitive polynomials represent units." Journal of Algebra 77.1 (1982): 138-157.  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869382902824

As an example of how this hypothesis may be used, this class of rings has a primitive element theorem and normal basis theorem, see

- Paques, A. "On the primitive element and normal basis theorems." Communications in Algebra 16.3 (1988): 443-455.
  https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927878808823581?journalCode=lagb20